# Impact of plural vs singular names

Tags: user-behavior, psychology, experience, user-engagement, trust

I've just bought a domain for my mobile app/website project, and an interesting question popped to my mind.
I don't know what would be the impact of this decision in terms of user experience, user trust, brand trust etc'.

The two names are :

**1)** WaiseWatch.com

**2)** WaiseWatch**es**.com

What do you guys think? What would generate more uniqueness/ trust?

Comment: It depends. Are you only talking about the domain name only or are you talking about the name of the brand itself ?

Comment: @ArkDeus Both eventually, best practice would make the domain name the brand name, won't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this :

https://econsultancy.com/blog/3821-the-25-factors-behind-brilliant-brand-domain-names/

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/should-i-use-singular-or-plural-nouns-in-a-domain-name-and-why

These two articles will tell you slightly different things, I let you judge which one convince you the most. But here is my approach :

If your product is called the Waise Watch, and you're only selling your Waise Watch on that site, go for singular. WaiseWatch.com will definitely call the user's attention on THE one and only Waise Watch. If you are, for example a watch retailer, and you sell many different watches, then go for the plural name. The impression will be like "the watches sold by Waise" or something like that.

Anyway, the singular will emphasize the fact that your product is unique, plural will emphasize the fact that you're selling a wide range of things.

But obviously, the best option if you want to have maximum visibility would be to buy the two.

Edit : look at this regarding domain name matching branding name http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2012-05-11/when-should-domain-names-match-company-names , there is a lot of pertinent information.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your detailed answer! The website is retail shop, I'm selling wide range of watches. I'm guessing that most people will search for watches and not watch. Tho, i have this feeling that watches soon less luxurious / more cheap than watch. What do you think?

Comment: In that case I would definitely go with the plural. I understand your feeling about the singular because uniqueness is also related to luxurious things, the more it is unique, the more it is valuable. But the fact that you are actually selling watches is way more important. WaiseWatch.com may confuse the user about what the WaiseWatch really is. But the user looking for watches will instantly understand that Waise Watches has a broad range of watches to sell. Therefore, it is the graphical design which should vehiculate the idea of luxury.

Comment: Perfectly summed. We will go with plural :) Thank you sir!

Comment: You are very welcome